# why iframe not updating the entire form asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, iframe, file-upload, upload

for fileupload i used iframe,I have javascript like this

```
 function uploadFileUsingAnIframe(iFrame_id, form_id) {
            var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
            iframe.setAttribute("id", iFrame_id);
            iframe.setAttribute("name", iFrame_id);
            iframe.setAttribute("width", "0");
            iframe.setAttribute("height", "0");
            iframe.setAttribute("border", "0");
            iframe.setAttribute("style", "width: 0px; height:0px; border: none;");

            document.body.appendChild(iframe);
            document.getElementById(form_id).target = iFrame_id;

        }
```

and in the view/aspx as

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("AddFile", "uploadfile", FormMethod.Post, new
   {
       id = "uploadform",
       enctype = "multipart/form-data",
       target = "uploadFileFrame",
       onsubmit = "javascript:uploadFileUsingAnIframe('uploadFileFrame','uploadform');"
   }))
```

%>

```
{ %>
<input type="file" id="addedFile" name="addedFile" /><br />
    <input type="submit" id="addfile" value="Addfile" />
          <div id="upload">
       //here i show the uploaded filenames from model </div>

<%} %>
```

problem is the div is not showing latest means the view is not updating the model values  ,may be the target or the parameters to be passed to the javascript function need to be changed to get required view. guys could you help me out.

thank you,
michaeld

Answer (score 1):

You can use Valums Uploader. It's very good upload js library that can be easily customized and already have iframe file upload functionality.

http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

Comment: the uploader is good jack, but my requirement is to try without any plug in.